# NSSplitView: custom double click handler

Tags: swift, cocoa, divider, nssplitview

I'm trying to find out how can I detect a double-click on the NSSplitView divider. It seems to me that divider is exposed neither to the NSSplitViewDelegate, nor to the NSSplitViewController.

What I have found so far is that the divider is an instance of NSSplitDividerView which is a private class, thus cannot extend or subclass it.

Could you put me back on the correct track of investigation?

Thanks.

Comment: The way I read the NSSplitViewController class, the divider should be included as one of the splitViewItems. Have you checked to see whether that's true? If so, then NSViewController is likely the way to go; if not, then I can suggest another (more hackish) approach. I could whip up a some sample code later tonight, but if you happen to know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to subclass `NSSplitView` and override `mouseDown(with:)`. Check if the location of the event is between the subviews.

```
override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    if event.clickCount == 2 {
        let location = self.convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil)
        if location.x > NSMaxX(self.arrangedSubviews[0].frame) && location.x < NSMinX(self.arrangedSubviews[1].frame) {
            Swift.print("doubleclick")
            return
        }
    }
    super.mouseDown(with: event)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can implement the `optional func splitView(_ splitView: NSSplitView, shouldCollapseSubview subview: NSView, forDoubleClickOnDividerAt dividerIndex: Int) -> Bool` method in the split view's delegate object, return `false`, and then implement whatever custom action you want instead.

Comment: `shouldCollapseSubview` is deprecated. It is not called in macOS 10.13. `splitView:doubleClickedOnDividerAtIndex:` is but it isn't public API.

Comment: I am aware of that deprecated function. I was not aware of the `splitView:doubleClickedOnDividerAtIndex:`, that is a good point. However, I'd like to stay with public API if possible.